# How to attach jQuery to the PhantomJS driver of Selenium (Python bindings)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, selenium, phantomjs

I am using the Python bindings for Selenium and the PhantomJS driver. I want to be able to manipulate the DOM using WebDriver.execute_script() to run JavaScript code, but I also want to make use of JQuery. Problem is the site I'm dealing with doesn't make use of JQuery so I have to load it myself into the page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a way to add jQuery dynamically using webdriver.

First include the jquery script to the head section of the html document with:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webdriver;
js.executeScript( jScript );
```

Where jsScript it the raw string:

```
var script = document.createElement('script'); 
script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Note that this implementation is not specific to GhostDriver(PhantomJS webdriver's name) and can be reused with the other webdrivers. The downside of this implementation is that if you navigate to another page, you'll have to load jQuery again.

I Hope I helped you a bit!